# rbegin() of a boost::iterator_range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, reverse, traversal

I refactored a class that used a single list of elements so it now uses a list of such lists.
To minimize the changes in derived classes, I implemented a custom `iterator` using `boost::iterator_facade`and also a method to get a `boost::iterator_range<iterator>` that can be used for iterating instead of the original list.

This appears to work except in one place where `rbegin()` is used. `boost::iterator_range` does not appear to support something like that.

*What would be a simple way of getting the range's last element?*

I'm using VS2008 SP1, i.e. only some C++11 support in std::tr1, and boost is obviously available, too.

```
typedef std::deque<MyData> DataList;

class MyClass : private boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    void AppendData(DataList* newData    

private:
    typedef std::deque<DataList*> ListOfDatatLists;

    /**
     * Custom iterator.
     * The content is not meant to be modified so this iterator operates on const lists only.
     */
    class iterator
        : public boost::iterator_facade <
        iterator,
        MyData,
        boost::forward_traversal_tag // Only forward iteration necessary
        >
    {
    public:
        static boost::iterator_range<iterator> range(const ListOfDataLists * pListOfLists);

    private:
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        iterator(const ListOfDataLists * pListOfLists = NULL) : m_pListOfLists(pListOfLists) {}

        /// \name Implementations for boost base class
        //{@
        bool equal(iterator const & other) const;
        MyData & dereference() const;
        void increment();
        difference_type distance_to(const iterator & other) const;
        //@}

        const ListOfDataLists * m_pListOfLists;
        ListOfDataLists::const_iterator m_listIt; ///< The current list of data items
        DataList::const_iterator m_dataIt; ///< An iterator of the current list
    };


    ListOfResultLists m_dataLists;


protected:
    typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<CLockedResults> SpLockedResults;

    /// For use by derived classes instead of the former single list
    boost::iterator_range<iterator> GetData() const;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One solution, if possible, is to allow bidirectional or random access traversal.  This would allow you to get call `range.end() --` (assuming the range isn't empty).  This would also allow you to reverse the range using the `reversed` boost range adaptor.
2. The other solution is to obtain the iterators from the range using `begin()/end()` and using `std::distance` to determine the distance between the two iterators. You could then use `std::advance` the beginning iterator one less than the distance to move to the last element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I went for the bidirectional iterators.